# Laravel 5.2 One to One Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

Here scenario is :

I have 2 tables.

```
1. User
2. Post
```

User can sign in, login and logout, he can create his own profile, he can update it.

Post table contains individual user info, when user create his profile this table contains the data and from this table user can update the data also.

The problem is I can create the User, But couldn't update it. How do I solve this problem?

```
 Undefined property:
 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$first_name (View:
 C:\xampp\htdocs\protfolio\resources\views\update.blade.php)
```

Here is my User Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

     public function post()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Post'); 
    }
}
```

Here is the post Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
     public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); //Profile is your profile model
    }
}
```

here is the post controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Post;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class PostController extends Controller
{


   public function getDashboard()
   {        
     $posts = Post::all();
          return view('dashboard',['posts'=>$posts]);  
    }


    public function postUpdate(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'first_name'=> 'required|max:120',
            'middle_name'=> 'required|max:120',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:120',
            'gender'=> 'required',
            'dob'=>'required',
            'nationality'=>'required',
            'nid'=>'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'phone_no'=>'required',
            'about_me'=>'required',
            ]);
        $post = Post::find($request['postId']);
        if (Auth::user() != $post->user) {
            return redirect()->back();
        }
         $post->first_name = $request['first_name'];
        $post->middle_name = $request['middle_name'];
        $post->last_name = $request['last_name'];
        $post->gender = $request['gender'];
        $post->dob = $request['dob'];
        $post->nationality = $request['nationality'];
        $post->nid = $request['nid'];
        $post->email = $request['email'];
        $post->phone_no = $request['phone_no'];
        $post->about_me = $request['about_me']; 
        $post->update();
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');        
    }

  public function postCreate(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
      'first_name'=> 'required|max:120',
      'middle_name'=> 'required|max:120',
      'last_name' => 'required|max:120',
      'gender'=> 'required',
      'dob'=>'required',
      'nationality'=>'required',
      'nid'=>'required',
      'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
      'phone_no'=>'required',
      'about_me'=>'required',
        ]);

    $post = new Post();
        $post->first_name = $request['first_name'];
        $post->middle_name = $request['middle_name'];
        $post->last_name = $request['last_name'];
        $post->gender = $request['gender'];
        $post->dob = $request['dob'];
        $post->nationality = $request['nationality'];
        $post->nid = $request['nid'];
        $post->email = $request['email'];
        $post->phone_no = $request['phone_no'];
        $post->about_me = $request['about_me'];        
      $message='There was an Error';
        if( $request->user()->post()->save($post)){
          $message = "Profile Created successfully";
        }
        return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message' => $message]);

  }
}
```

Here is the User Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function getAccount()
    {  

     $posts = Post::all();
        return view('update',['user'=>Auth::user()],['posts'=>$posts]);
    }

    public function getCreate()
      {        
        return view('create',['user'=>Auth::user()]);
      }
}
```

Here is my update.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

    @section('content')
         @include('includes.message-block')
         <div class="container" >
                <h3> Create course </h3>
            {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'update','class'=>'form-horizontal','method'=>'POST'))  !!}
            {!! Form::token(); !!}
            {!!   csrf_field() ; !!} 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control"   value="{{$posts->first_name}}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Middle Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="middle_name" class="form-control"  value="{{$posts->middle_name}}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control"   value="{{$posts->last_name}}">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Gender</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="gender" value="{{$posts->gender}}">
                        <option>Male</option>
                        <option>Female</option>     
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Date Of Birth</label>  
                    <input type="date" name="dob" class="form-control"  value="{{$posts->dob}}">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Nationality</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nationality" class="form-control"   value="{{$posts->nationality}}">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>NID</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nid" class="form-control"   value="{{$posts->nid}}">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control"   value="{{$posts->email}}">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" name="phone_no" class="form-control"   value="{{$posts->phone_no}}">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>About Me</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="about_me"  rows="3">"{{$posts->about_me}}"</textarea>
                </div>


                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>

     @endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$posts->first()->first_name` and use same in all other variable in update page

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the User Model Class Definition, Please try the following code here:

**User Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    use Authenticatable;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
public function getAccount()
{  

 $posts = Post::all();
    return view('update',['user'=>Auth::user()],['posts'=>$posts]);
}
```

The Post::all() get all the posts from your table, not the one that belongs to the user. (I assume that this is what you want).

To get the post associated with the current logged user, you can try this:

```
$posts = Auth::user()->post
```

Comment: Nope, still the same problem!

Comment: can you var_dump($posts) in your view and see what propertis you get?